# Makefile ignoring included rules

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile for a very basic c++ program. I'm trying to implement the automatic generation of dependencies by running g++ with the -M flag, storing this output in a `.d` file, and then including those `.d` files in my main makefile. The makefile content is below

```
CC=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11

SOURCEDIR=src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)

BUILDDIR=build
OBJDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/objs
OBJS=$(SOURCES:$(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEP_FILES = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

OUTFILE=hello.out


$(OUTFILE) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CPPFLAGS)

include $(DEP_FILES)
$(OBJDIR)/%.d : $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:.d=.o) > $@

$(DEP_FILES) : | $(OBJDIR)
$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(BUILDDIR) -r
    rm -f *~ 
    rm -f $(OUTFILE)
```

When I run `make`, the directory `build/objs/` is generated and a `.d` file is generated with rules in it. Here's `main.d` file:

```
build/objs/main.o: src/main.cpp src/main.h
```

And here's the `myfunc.d` file:

```
build/objs/myfunc.o: src/myfunc.cpp src/main.h
```

**Here's the issue**
Since I'm calling include on these .d files, I'd expect the .o files which they specify to then be created, and then the main outfile to be created as the main rule. However, make creates the `.d` files, and then skips directly to the main compilation step without creating any .o files:

```
g++ -o hello.out build/objs/myfunc.o build/objs/main.o -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11
```

This fails with the following error, since the `.o` files are never created:

```
g++: error: build/objs/myfunc.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: build/objs/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

How can I use this makefile to generate the `.o` files necessary for g++? Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you try to add to your main Makefile a rule to create object files from source files. Not just the dependencies, but a recipe with a compilation command.

Comment: A rule without a recipe won't magically create .o file. And a built-in rule is not appropriate here, as $(SOURCEDIR) and $(OBJDIR) are different. So you still have to write a compilation rule by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you got your makefile working but I just wanted to add a few things you might want to consider for future projects. I recommend using the vpath variable rather than specifying `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` in your makefile recipes. I actually read somewhere that it's not "cannon" to build object files in a separate directory, but in the cursory search I conducted before posting, I couldn't find the document.

That being said, I wrote a makefile that does what you wanted; it builds the output folder, generates the dependencies, and compiles the program. I specifically included the `$(COMPILE.cpp)` definition so you could see what it's composed of. `$(CC)` is specifically the C compiler, and `$(CFLAGS)` is specifically flags for the C compiler. They're just variables, obviously, so you can change them like you did and it will work fine, but the main think to keep in mind is that whoever uses your programs will expect to be able to configure the compilation as they see fit. This means they will set the `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` expecting to set the C++ compiler and flags. `$(CPPFLAGS)` stands for C/C++ Preprocessor flags.

It's not the cleanest makefile, and if I was to change something, I would just compile the object files in place and save myself that headache. That cuts down on unnecessary make hacking, but for the purposes of answering your question, here it is. Anyways I hope this helps you somewhat, let me know if you have any questions.

---

Oh yea, I almost forgot; notice I changed your `make clean` script. I used `$(RM)` instead of simply `rm -f`. When you use utilities in your makefiles, you want to [use them as variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Utilities-in-Makefiles.html#Utilities-in-Makefiles). Again, this is to allow your users as much freedom and flexibility as possible when they're compiling your program.

---

```
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.hpp include
vpath %.o build/objs
vpath %.d build/objs

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .hpp .o .d

SRCDIR          = src
INCLUDESDIR     = include
BUILDDIR        = build
OBJDIR          = $(BUILDDIR)/objs

SRCS            = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS            = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(notdir $(SRCS)))
DEP_FILES       = $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $(OBJS))

INCLUDE_DIRS    = -I $(INCLUDESDIR)

CXX             = g++
CPPFLAGS        = 
CXXFLAGS        = -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11

PROGRAM         = hello.out

COMPILE.cpp     = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(TARGET_ARCH)

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): %: $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.cpp) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $^) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE.cpp) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ $<

%.d: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $^ -MM -MT $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(@:.d=.o)) > $(OBJDIR)/$@

include $(DEP_FILES)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo $(RM)
    $(RM) $(BUILDDIR) -r
    $(RM) *~ 
    $(RM) $(PROGRAM)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I used most of your changes relating to conventional uses of variables, but had problems using the vpath variable. In the end I found this link which describes why that's not a good idea for designating target paths with vpath: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

Comment: Interesting article, he does make some really good points. I will say though that there is a difference between the VPATH and vpath declarations. VPATH will tell make to search for every file in every location declared, whereas the vpath declarations in the example specify a folder location for each file extension, so (at least as I learned it) it's a little better. That's exactly the site I was looking for but couldn't find, by the way, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar issue, here's the correct solution is in the comments. Here for convenience: The included `.d` files generate dependencies but not a recipe for making the `.o` files, and since I'm putting things in various directories the default rule doesn't work here, so the `.o` files aren't created. The solution was to add in the following rule to my main makefile.

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o :
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Thanks Matt and Renaud for your answers!

Comment: Did you by any chance try setting the `vpath` variable rather than specifying the `$(OBJDIR)` in the requirement like this?